# setText to Fragment from within Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying in vain to simply take a value from FormActivity and use it to fill a EditText in a Fragment. I have to wait for activity to retrieve the value from a remote server and populate the local SQLite table with it, this means no solution I have tried from within the fragment has worked (null error because it hasn't been populated that early). 
I need help.

Relevant section of FormActivity.java

```
public void DrawText() {
        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        if (user.size() != 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "string surname: " + surname);

            // Displaying the user details on the fragment

            FirstFragment f1 = new FirstFragment();

            //put info into a bundle to pass to fragments
            Bundle drawbundle = new Bundle();
            drawbundle.putString("surname", surname);

            f1.setArguments(drawbundle);

            FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
            FT.add(R.id.something, f1);
            FT.commit();

        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "table was empty");
        }
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("@string/form_instruct");
                case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
                case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
                case 3: return FourthFragment.newInstance("FourthFragment, Instance 1");
                //case 4: return FifthFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
                default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Default");

            }
        }
```

Obviously, id.something is not correct, I do not know how to get the id. I read I can use a tag, but my attempt at that did not work. I tried the following:

```
FirstFragment fragA = (FirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragA");
```

Here is my FirstFragment.java

```
public class FirstFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    //create variables & Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = FirstFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText inputTitle;
    private EditText inputName;
    private EditText inputSurname;
    //private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

        inputSurname = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.surnameText);
        inputSurname.setText(getArguments().getString("surname"));

        return v;
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
```

I'm going around in circles with this, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a `ContentProvider` you could use a `ContentObserver` to get notified when your table is filled up, and when `onChange` is invoked, you can update the `TextView`. If you are not using a `ContentProvider`, yo could use the `LocalBroadcastManger` and a `BroadcastReceiver` to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Create interface implement your fragment with it after fragment creation access your activity and save your interface reference in activity, after your operation will complete access your method from activity using saved interface reference and update your fragment.
Second option add your fragment with tag and using this fragment manager find your fragment by tag than you have the reference of your fragment than simply call your method inside your activity

Comment: So, in order to set the tag I would use this?

FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
            FT.add(R.id.something, f1);
            FT.commit();

I have no idea what 'R.id.something' should be. I am reading it should be the container, which is 'container'. That doesn't work. Unless I put this code into the fragment itself?